# I have a problem with components in angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, components, angular-components, angular-compiler

Hello I'm newbie in Angular and  took a course in this framework and I have a problem with an error nd I don't understand how to fix it.
import {Component } from '@angular/core';

code:
@Component{{
selector: 'contador-app',
}}
//se le pone export para poder utilzar esta clase fuera de este archivo :3

```
export class contadorComponent{

}
```

**error message:**
(alias) const Component: ComponentDecorator
import Component
Supplies configuration metadata for an Angular component. Component decorator and metadata.

@publicApi

@Annotation

@publicApi

Declaration expected.ts(1146)

Comment: how did you make this component??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've accidently used curly brackets twice for the component decorator.

```
@Component >{{<
    selector: 'contador-app', >}}<
```

A component decorator looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'contador-app',
})
```

It is also common to specify the components html file and stylesheet with either
templateUrl: 'path to html-file' and styleUrls: ['path to stylesheet'], note that the latter is between brackets as you can specify one or more paths to a stylesheet. There's also the option to write html / css directly in the component decorator using

```
template: 'html-code'
```

and / or

```
styles: 'css-code'.
```

Also Purvang raises a good question in the comments on how you went about to create the component? If you did it manually you have to make sure it is imported correctly in to the responsible module as the component needs to be made known by angular when the app is bootstrapped otherwise it wont render. If you are new it may serve better to use the ng generate command to let the CLI generate a component for you it looks like this:

```
ng generate component your-component-name
```

For more info about decorators i referenced this bloggpost:
https://www.netjstech.com/2020/03/angular-component-decorator.html

Comment: thanks 4 your help :3

Comment: No problem! Please consider accepting my answer as a solution if you feel it helped you.

Comment: Hi tommi how are u? I cannot vote for your answer when I press the arrow  (i don't know if it has a technical name) it requires me to have a reputation of 15: message attached: 
what I could do was to select the ticket, I do not know if that also serves, sorry for the delay of my response.

Comment: @JaimeWrighton No worries! The arrow is to upvote a question / answer, it helps determine which are most useful and appropiate, referenced from: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up . But the checkmark is used for accepting the answer as a solution, which you've done (you can see the green checkmark on my answer now) so thank you for that! Have a good weekend